# Expression.IsFalse is Unknown?

Tags: linq, expression-trees

I am getting the following error when I ultimately try to run the query

> Unknown LINQ expression of type 'IsFalse'

this is the code

```
private static IQueryable<T> QueryMethod<T>(
    IQueryable<T> query,
    QueryableRequestMessage.WhereClause.Rule rule,
    Type type,
    string methodName,
    Expression property,
    Expression value,
    string op,
    ParameterExpression parameter
) where T : class
{
    var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName, new[] { type });
    var call = Expression.Call(property, methodInfo, value);
    var expression = rule.Op.Equals(op)
                            ? Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, parameter)
                            : Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.IsFalse(call), parameter);
    query = query.Where(expression);
    return query;
}
```

The important variables have the following values

```
query: an IQueryable that I am building up
type: String
methodName: "EndsWith"
rule.Op: "ne" //Not Ends With
op: "ew"
value: "somestring"
```

Basically, if op and rule.Op are equal, it just runs the methodName (EndsWith) and filters accordingly.  However, If they are different, I want to negate the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are not doing anything wrong; your LINQ provider simply does not know how to deal with the expression tree instance that `Expression.IsFalse` returns so it complains.

You can try to manually construct the "is false" expression tree yourself, which should work:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
   Expression.Equal(call, Expression.Constant(false)),
   parameter)
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3)

Comment: @CaffGeek: That's not the LINQ provider. The provider is Linq to Entities, Linq to SQL or some such.